# Service worker is not being used on non root path

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I've got a web-app thats deployed to the non root path of a static server. That is `MyApp` when built is deployed to a path/folder `https://example.com/myapp`.

`MyApp` is using vue and webpack so I've added the `GenerateSW` workbox plugin with the standard config. It's registering, adding all the files I need to the cache, but it's not being used.

My service worker is registering with scriptURL `https://example.com/myapp/service-worker.js` and scope `https://example.com/myapp/`. My cache storage has my files `/myapp/index.html?__WB_REVISION_...` `/myapp/app.<hash>.js?__WB_REVISION_..` and so on. However the service worker is still not controlling the page, ie `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is returning null.

I've seen this https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/troubleshoot-and-debug#common_problems but unlike in this situation I don't want the service worker having the root scope.

Am I missing any config options?

Answer (score 0):

`controlling` is sometimes null depending on where you are in the service worker lifecycle. When controlling is null you listen for the `controllerchange` event on the serviceworker object. My code just assumes everything is ok when the `controllerchange` event is dispatched, but you could check for `serviceWorker.controller !== null` before invoking the `resolve` method.

```
const controllerPromise = window.navigator.serviceWorker
  .register('https://example.com/myapp/service-worker.js')
  .then(() => window.navigator.serviceWorker.ready)
  .then(() => {
    if (window.navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
      return Promise.resolve(window.navigator.serviceWorker.controller);
    }
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      window.navigator.serviceWorker
        .addEventListener('controllerchange', () => resolve(window.navigator.serviceWorker.controller))
    );
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this as bellow:

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/myapp/service-worker.js',{scope: '/myapp/'});
    }
```

in manifist.json

```
"start_url": "/myapp/",
```

**The scope must be `/myapp/` the `/myapp` will not work!**